# Syntax error in Merge statement SQL

Tags: merge, insert, sql-update, ssms, target

I have two other questions about this but this one is more focused. The Merge statement's basic structure is given below. In the interest of time and length, I have summarized some of the details Originally, I was going to try to merge 8 into 1. That has been a fruitless venture so I have narrowed it down. For this one, I am trying to combine industry21 and industry4 knowing that there are 8 rows of primary key duplication. The primary key is a compound one comprised of 9 fields (not sure if that is relevant). They are 13 foreign keys.

From looking at the code below, can someone see why I would get an incorrect syntax on the = sign on the first bold item. Next on the same bold line, why when I hover over the . between source and periodtype on the same line do I get an error about "Merge Statement must be terminated in a column"

```
Merge industry4 AS TARGET
USING industry21 as SOURCE
ON (target.primarykey1 = Source.primarykey1) or (target.primarykey2 = 
Source.primarykey2) or.....  (target.primarykey9 = Source.primarykey9)

--When records are matched, update 
--the records if there is any change

WHEN MATCHED AND
TARGET.foreignkey1 <> SOURCE.foreignkey1
OR .... TARGET.foreignkey13 <> SOURCE.foreignkey2
THEN
UPDATE SET TARGET.pk1 = SOURCE.pk1,
TARGET.pk2 = SOURCE.pk2
**TARGET.periodtype(pk5) = SOURCE.periodtype (pk5)**
.....
TARGET.fk13 = SOURCE.fk13

--When no records are matched, insert
--the incoming records from source
--table to target table

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (fieids 1-22)
VALUES (SOURCE.pk1, SOURCE.pk2......SOURCE.fk13)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the task using the following code. It is not related to my original question but apparently merge statements are not the best nor popular way to do this.

```
SELECT x.* 
INTO [NEW_TABLE]
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2) x
```